# How to configure lazygit with git?

Tags: git

The lazygit application is a git client that is supposed to be simple to use.

I have a `.gitconfig` file:

```
[user]
  email = mittiprovence@yahoo.se
  name = Stephane Eybert
[alias]
  ss = status
  ap = add -p
  co = checkout
  unadd = reset
[core]
  pager = delta
  whitespace = cr-at-eol
  editor = vim
[filter "lfs"]
  process = git-lfs filter-process
  required = true
  clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
  smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
[merge]
  conflictStyle = diff3
  tool = meld
[push]
  ff = only
[fetch]
  prune = true
[diff]
  color = true
  tool = vimdiff
[color]
  diff = auto
  status = always
  branch = auto
[delta]
  side-by-side = true
  line-numbers = true
  navigate = true
  light = true
```

And I have a `~/.config/lazygit/config.yml` file:

```
git:
  showIcons: true
  paging:
    useConfig: true
```

But it feels like this configuration is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct format

```
gui:
  showIcons: true
git:
  paging:
    useConfig: true
```

More information can be found in the [docs](https://github.com/jesseduffield/lazygit/blob/master/docs/Config.md).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).